# Elasticsearch query aggregation filters range advice needed

Tags: elasticsearch

Dears,

How to modify such query to add additional condition to first range "0nn"?

I need to find only such documents which meet such conditions:
`ci.a": { "gte": 0,"lte": 99} and ci.b like "(??1?) or (??3?) or (??5?) or (??7?) or (??9?)"`

```
POST /log-2020-06-29/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "filter": [
      {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "2020-06-29T07:22:01",
            "lte": "2020-06-29T11:31:01"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "mti": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "0nn" : { "range": {"ci.a": { "gte": 0,"lte": 99}}},
          "4nn" : { "range": {"ci.a": { "gte": 400,"lte": 499}}},
          "1nn-2nn" : { "range": {"ci.a": { "gte": 100,"lte": 299}}},
          "9nn" : { "range": {"ci.a": { "gte": 900,"lte": 999}}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Can you add sample doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into [`regexp` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) for this -- your `ci.a` and `ci.b` fields are textual so `range` queries may not be optimal:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "ci.a": "0[0-9]{2}"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "ci.b": "[0-9]{2}[3|5|7|9][0-9]{1}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The same approach could then be used within your `filters` aggs.

*Note that regexp/wildcard queries tend to be slow but, depending on your index size, this may not be of concern.*

Comment: Thanks @joe I'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
{
          "ci.b" : "9930",
          "ci.realm" : "AAAABBBB",
          "tags" : [
            "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2020-07-07T12:10:56.381Z",
          "agent" : {
            "type" : "filebeat",
            "hostname" : "srv1",
            "version" : "7.5.2",
            "ephemeral_id" : "7c323287-12bb-4ca53218b-05e9c32322b",
            "id" : "5e823321-60a4-422d-9823-32557cb07bcb"
          },
          "event" : {
            "timezone" : "CEST"
          },
          "ci.kkk" : "413500000001",
          "ci.a" : "000",
          "input" : {
            "type" : "log"
          },
          "log" : {
            "file" : {
              "path" : "/home/apps/kot.log"
            },
            "flags" : [
              "multiline"
            ],
            "offset" : 13196
          },
          "date" : "2020-07-07T14:10:56.381",
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "1.1.0"
          },
          "host" : {
            "name" : "srv1",
            "containerized" : false,
            "architecture" : "x86_64",
            "os" : {
              "name" : "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server",
              "version" : "7.7 (Maipo)",
              "kernel" : "3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64",
              "family" : "redhat",
              "platform" : "rhel",
              "codename" : "Maipo"
            },
            "hostname" : "srv1",
            "id" : "c0196dd9ce8e48f9a4a393fbc2927134"
          },
          "@version" : "1",
          "message" : """<log realm="AAAABBBB" at="2020-07-07T14:10:56.381" lifespan="3681ms">
</log>"""
}
```

Comment: Tip: don't answer the question with something that should've been an edit instead.